# поиск с даты по дату SQL PHP

Tags: php, sql

подскажите как лучше реализовать выборку по дате SQL запросом?
Нужно получить все строки с базы по указанным датам.
Есть стартовая дата и конечная дата которую я получаю через датарангепикер
08/13/2022 - 08/13/2022

php $startDate & $endDate

Как мне правильно составить sql запрос в цикле? нужен именно правильно составленный sql.
В базе дата `date` формата CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 2022-08-07 11:42:15

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать совмещение BETWEEN и функций обработки времени, так как BETWEEN не включает границы интервалов.
Пример ниже, включая создание тестовой таблицы.

Не ваш случай, но для полноты картины:
Если "датарангепикер" начнет выдавать данные в полном DATETIME до секунд, а результат будет нужен с начала суток, то еще округление понадобится, иначе будете получать интервал ровно с той секунды, чтор выдана.

```
CREATE TABLE calls(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id VARCHAR (25),
    status_1 VARCHAR (25),
    ip VARCHAR (25), 
    device VARCHAR (25),
    created_at DATETIME    
);
INSERT INTO calls (user_id, status_1, ip, device,created_at)
    VALUES
    ("Петя", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.1', 'модем', '2018-05-25 21:25:54'),
    ("Маша", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.2', 'синхрофазатрон', '2018-05-25 22:22:22'),
    ("Вася", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.3', 'табурет', '2018-05-25 21:25:54'),
    ("Петя", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.1', 'модем', '2018-05-26 22:25:54'),
    ("Маша", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.2', 'синхрофазатрон', '2022-08-03 01:01:01'),
    ("Гена", "нет разницы", '192.168.0.4', 'ванна', '2022-08-04 01:01:01');

/*Сам запрос*/
SELECT * 
FROM calls 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN 
                 DATE_SUB('2018-05-25', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND 
                 DATE_ADD('2018-05-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Результат:

```
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | status_1    | ip          | device         | created_at          |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 1  | Петя    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.1 | модем          | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 |
| 2  | Маша    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.2 | синхрофазатрон | 2018-05-25 22:22:22 |
| 3  | Вася    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.3 | табурет        | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 |
| 4  | Петя    | нет разницы | 192.168.0.1 | модем          | 2018-05-26 22:25:54 |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+----------------+---------------------+
Affected rows: 4
```

Comment: Временный комментарий для недавно использующих этот сайт:  если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: Спасибо! да пришлось в DRP получать еще и временный интервал, и округлять по умолчанию, стартовую дату с 00:00:00 и конечную дату 23:59:59

Comment: Значит, вопрос неверно сформулировали:-) Еще остались вопросы? Если нет - можно принимать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать вот так

```
select * FROM table where and Date between '2022/08/13' and '2022/08/13'
```